# What does indicates null pages in google analytics ? and how to fix it?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, mean-stack

My website is developed with MEAN Stack, and integrated google analytics. For some pages it shows null page `/null` for up to 6, 7 users at the same time.
But can't find the reason, and don't know in which situations it occur. And how we can fix it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the path of the page is just that (due to an inconsistency of the site). Try checking which is the previous one to see if you can find a link that leads to this corrupt page.